# Xcode11 Archive fails: no such file or directory Objects-normal/arm64/UniversalSDK.SwiftFileList

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11, swift5

I am trying to build a universal framework from existing source code in Xcode11. 
When I Archive, it fails with following error:

```
/<unknown>:1:1: no such file or directory: '/Users/apple/SANDBOX/VoiceSampler/@/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceSampler-foeghskagbaeclezzbypkqnjnuos/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BuildUniversalSDK/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VoiceSampler.build/Release-iphoneos/UniversalSDK.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UniversalSDK.SwiftFileList'
```

/:1:1: no such file or directory: '/Users/apple/SANDBOX/VoiceSampler/@/Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VoiceSampler-foeghskagbaeclezzbypkqnjnuos/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BuildUniversalSDK/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VoiceSampler.build/Release-iphoneos/UniversalSDK.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UniversalSDK.SwiftFileList'

I was able to Archive the same in Xcode 10.3 earlier. Not sure what changed.

[image]

Please help me solve this Archive error.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know if it helps, but for me it happens when I run the Swift compiler manually from inside XCode (a script which builds a separate Swift framework). XCode sets the environment variable `SWIFT_RESPONSE_FILE_PATH_normal_x86_64` (variant and architecture) which points to that particular missing `.SwiftFileList` file. Unsetting this environmant variable solved the issue for us.

This is how we unset it in the external script:

```
for V in ${BUILD_VARIANTS}; do
    for A in ${ARCHS}; do
        unset SWIFT_RESPONSE_FILE_PATH_${V}_${A}
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was related with using the legacy build system instead of the new one (in Xcode 11). Once I switched to the New Build System (in File -> Workspace/Project Settings), these new lines started to appear in the build log:

```
WriteAuxiliaryFile /Users/.../XXXXXX.SwiftFileList (in target 'XXXX' from project 'XXX')
```